# How do I return a number in render arrays?

Tags: 8, blocks

I am building a module in Drupal 8. I am doing a query in database and I return the number of users and the number of nodes. I write of screen this numbers without errors, but I cannot write them in a block.

This is the code I am using.

#### Module file

```
/**
 * Implementa hook_theme ()
*/
function my_module_theme() {
  return array(
    'my_module_test' => array(
      'template' => 'test',
      'users' => NULL,
      'questions' => NULL,
    ),
  );
}
```

#### The class implementing the block

```
  namespace Drupal\my_module\Plugin\Block;
  use Drupal\minka_qa_core\FormatUtils;

  use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockBase;

  /**
   * Provides a 'Bloco' block.
   *
   * @Block(
   *  id = "bloco",
   *  admin_label = @Translation("Bloco"),
   * )
   */
   class Bloco extends BlockBase {

     /**
      * {@inheritdoc}
      */
     public function build() {
       //$count = $this->countTest();
       $example = $this->test();
       $example2 = $this->test2();

       print_r($example);
       printf('\n');
       print_r($example2);
       //$questions = $this->countTest2();
       /*$build = [];
       $build['bloco']['#theme'] = 'my_module_test';
       $build['bloco']['#plaint_text'] = 'Questões';
       $build['bloco']['#users'] = $count;*/
       return [
         '#theme' => 'my_module_test',
         '#plain_text' => 'Questões',
         '#users' => $example,
         '#questions' => $example2,
       ];
   }

   public function test() {
     $query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
      ->condition('status', 1)
      ->condition('type', 'questoes');
     $nids = $query->count()->execute();

     return FormatUtils::formatNumber($nids);
   }

   public function test2(){
     $query = \Drupal::entityQuery('user')
      ->condition('status', 1);
     $nids = $query->count()->execute();

     return FormatUtils::formatNumber($nids);
   }
```

}

#### The template file

```
<div class="test">
  <p>Test twig template!</p>

  <p>user: {{ users }}</p>
</div>
```

Why isn't my code working?

Answer (score 2):

There is a mismatch in `hook_theme()`, template is "test", elsewhere "my_module_test". And the return array has three levels, with the keys `variables` and `template` in the second level and the twig parameters in the third:

```
  return [
    'loremipsum' => [
      'variables' => [
        'source_text' => NULL,
      ],
      'template' => 'loremipsum',
    ],
  ];
```